# iTunes Connect does not display languages in Europe

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

In iTunes Connect, I am trying to add more language options to my project. But I am not getting the list of all the languages in Europe. Any leads on how to change the list?

[image: list of languages in iTunes Connect]

Comment: How about scrolling? I recommend viewing that page in Safari and making the window as big as possible. UX/UI of iTunes Connect is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

The list contains all the available languages that are available for metadata localization in the App Store and it's **not expandable**.

Note that metadata localization is not equivalent with your app's language support; an app can still support languages that are not in that list.

Comment: I mean the language is available for metadata localization in the App store. But I do not see ''Finninsh in my listings.